# Looping animations with duration, Swift 4

Tags: swift, loops, animation, race-condition

I have an image that I want to move 10 separate times in a row. Each time I want it to do a check, as notated by the print statement of checkForStuff. I noticed that the loop starts and it times out while the first of the 10 moves occurs. Any thoughts on how to chain animations, or do I need to manually write each chain in the sequential closure?

```
@objc func moveBox(sender: UIButton!) {
    print("Started")
    let imageToMove = UIImageView()
    imageToMove.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 50, height: 50)
    imageToMove.backgroundColor = .red
    self.view.addSubview(imageToMove)

    var counter = 0
    var altitude = 100


    while counter <= 10 {
        print("looping")
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            imageToMove.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: altitude, width: 50, height: 50)
        }, completion: { finished in
            counter += 1
            altitude += 50
            print("Check For Stuff")
        })
    }

}
```

In short, in should move 50 pixels down, execute the closure, move 50 pixels down again. and again, and again.

Comment: Use recursion not a while loop.

Comment: Setup all the animations with keyframes? Should be pretty straightforward in your case, and removes the need for recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Recursion as suggested by @matt

```
 func animate(view: UIView, altitude: Int, numberOfTime: Int ) {

        if numberOfTime == 0 { return }

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {

            view.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: altitude, width: 50, height: 50)
        }, completion: { finished in
            self.animate(view: view, altitude: altitude + 50, numberOfTime: numberOfTime - 1)
        })
    }
```

Use this as

```
@objc func moveBox(sender: UIButton!) {
    print("Started")
    let imageToMove = UIImageView()
    imageToMove.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 50, height: 50)
    imageToMove.backgroundColor = .red
    self.view.addSubview(imageToMove)

    animate(view: imageToMove, altitude: 100, numberOfTime: 10)
}
```